# I have disabled all rules in firewall, but still can tracert from LAN

Tags: freebsd, firewall, pfsense, icmp

I have disabled all positive rules in firewall on my `pfSense` box, and I can't browse Web, but I still can

```
tracert 10.10.0.251
```

from `LAN` machine and receive 3 hops from my ISP (behind the router).

How is this possible?

Comment: Router runs `FreeBSD/pfSense`, LAN machine runs `Windows` I am doing tracert from `Windows` machine and seeing hops from behind router despite the fact all rules are disabled.

Comment: Are you allowing ICMP packets out?

Comment: What's your firewall policy (default action without rules)?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro don't see this, how to check?

Comment: @roaima it should be deny all.

Comment: @Dims I have no longer access to "my" PfSenses, left job. I am travelling today, so will be off the grid for the greater part of the day.

Comment: Cannot remember the details, I think you have explicitly to block ICMP for it to be blocked. Could you add a rule dropping ICMP?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro may be, but I don't want them to drop, I want them to pass to VPN. Initially it was working but then stopped. I need to find actor who is reponsible for this.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the default rules are allowing ICMP for the outside.

`tracert` in Windows also is implement differently than in Unix/Linux; while the traditional Unix `traceroute` sends UDP packets, the Windows `tracert` implementation sends ICMP packets to do the path probes.